# Codeigniter: updating multiple rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 2 and I wanted to update multiple rows.

**Model**

Here is my model, but, the problem is, the first row only is updated.

```
 foreach ($this->input->post('qty') as $key => $value) {
            $data = array(
                   'item_quantity' => $value,
                   'discount' => $this->input->post('discount')[$key],
                   'senior' => $this->input->post('qty')[$key]
            );

            $this->db->where('item_id', $this->input->post('item_id')[$key]);
            $this->db->where('request_id', $this->input->post('request_id'));
            return $this->db->update('medical_request_items', $data);  
        }
```

On the other side, I managed to do this.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                                    {

                                       echo '<tr>';
                                       echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="' . $row->item_id . '">';
                                       echo '<td>' . $x++ . '</td>';
                                       echo '<td>' . $row->item_id . '</td>';
                                       echo '<td>' . $row->item_name . '</td>';
                                       echo '<td><input type="text" size="1" name="qty[]" value="' . $row->item_quantity . '"></td>';
                                       echo '<td>' . $row->item_retailprice . '</td>';
                                       echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" name="discount[]" value="' . $row->discount . '"></td>';
                                       echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" name="senior[]" value="' . $row->senior . '"></td>';
                                       echo '<td>' . ($row->item_quantity * $row->item_retailprice) . '</td>';
                                       echo '<td>' . (($row->item_quantity * $row->item_retailprice)-($row->item_quantity * $row->discount)-($row->item_quantity * $row->senior)) . '</td>';
                                       echo '</tr>';                                                  
                                    }
```

I tried to echo/print, and it is working fine. But it doesn't work on multiple update.

**EDIT**

So I manage to look out the `update_batch` yet, I have an error.

```
$data = array(
                    foreach ($this->input->post('qty') as $key => $value) {
                           array(
                              'request_id'      =>  $this->input->post('request_id'),
                              'item_id'         =>  $this->input->post('item_id')[$key],
                              'item_quantity'   =>  $value,
                              'discount'        =>  $this->input->post('discount')[$key],
                              'senior'          =>  $this->input->post('senior')[$key]
                           )
                    }
                );



        $this->db->update_batch('medical_request_items', $data, 'item_id, request_id');
```

Comment: What does $_POST contain? Please show the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting multiple arrays, but in your model you are only looping through one, so your where clauses will always be the same.

Comment: Do I have to loop it again?

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely foreach and update them one record at a time. but i think should also be able to use update batch to do all of them at once.

```
$this->db->update_batch('yourTableName', $updateData, 'field_to_use_for_key');
```

info for ci 2 
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

====

ok lets dig into the code

```
    // define an array 
    $requests = array() ; 


     foreach ($this->input->post('qty') as $key => $value) {

     // notice the brackets, very important $requests[] 
     // this will add to the same array in each loop

         $requests[] =      array(
             'request_id'      =>  $this->input->post('request_id'),
              'item_id'         =>  $this->input->post('item_id')[$key],
              'item_quantity'   =>  $value,
              'discount'        =>  $this->input->post('discount')[$key],
              'senior'          =>  $this->input->post('senior')[$key]
                           ) ; 


                    }


   // for testing only -- echo out your array so you can confirm its all good 
   echo 'here is requests array: <br><pre>' ; 

   print_r($requests) ; 

    echo '</pre>' ; 


// use one field to act as the key 
 $this->db->update_batch('medical_request_items', $requests, 'request_id');
```

so thats using one key. if you need more then one key or where conditions to do the update - then just update in the foreach loop. Also you are of course **validating any user data before updating**.

Comment: I'm having a difficulty on how to setup the array() for the items. Please check the post. I've updated it